# jQuery Animating Elements by Scrolling the page

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm trying to create a animation by scrolling the page, something like this:

```
$(function() {
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    var top = $(document).scrollTop();      
    if (top > 2200 && top < 2401) {
        if (top > 2200 && top < 2210) {
            $('#seta2').stop().animate({left: "826px"}, 300, "easeOutQuad" );
        }
        if (top > 2211 && top < 2220) {
            $('#seta2').stop().animate({left: "821px"}, 300, "easeOutQuad" );
        }
        if (top > 2221 && top < 2230) {
            $('#seta2').stop().animate({left: "816px"}, 300, "easeOutQuad" );
        }
        if (top > 2231 && top < 2240) {
            $('#seta2').stop().animate({left: "811px"}, 300, "easeOutQuad" );
        }
        if (top > 2241 && top < 2250) {
            $('#seta2').stop().animate({left: "806px"}, 300, "easeOutQuad" );
        }
        if (top > 2251 && top < 2260) {
            $('#seta2').stop().animate({left: "801px"}, 300, "easeOutQuad" );
        }
        if (top > 2261 && top < 2270) {
            $('#seta2').stop().animate({left: "796px"}, 300, "easeOutQuad" );
        }
        if (top > 2271 && top < 2280) {
            $('#seta2').stop().animate({left: "791px"}, 300, "easeOutQuad" );
        }
        if (top > 2281 && top < 2290) {
            $('#seta2').stop().animate({left: "786px"}, 300, "easeOutQuad" );
        }
        if (top > 2291 && top < 2300) {
            $('#seta2').stop().animate({left: "781px"}, 300, "easeOutQuad" );
        }
        if (top > 2301 && top < 2310) {
            $('#seta2').stop().animate({left: "776px"}, 300, "easeOutQuad" );
        }
        if (top > 2311 && top < 2320) {
            $('#seta2').stop().animate({left: "771px"}, 300, "easeOutQuad" );
        }
        if (top > 2321 && top < 2330) {
            $('#seta2').stop().animate({left: "766px"}, 300, "easeOutQuad" );
        }
        if (top > 2331 && top < 2340) {
            $('#seta2').stop().animate({left: "761px"}, 300, "easeOutQuad" );
        }
        if (top > 2341 && top < 2350) {
            $('#seta2').stop().animate({left: "756px"}, 300, "easeOutQuad" );
        }
        if (top > 2351 && top < 2360) {
            $('#seta2').stop().animate({left: "751px"}, 300, "easeOutQuad" );
        }
        if (top > 2361 && top < 2370) {
            $('#seta2').stop().animate({left: "746px"}, 300, "easeOutQuad" );
        }
        if (top > 2371 && top < 2380) {
            $('#seta2').stop().animate({left: "741px"}, 300, "easeOutQuad" );
        }
        if (top > 2381 && top < 2390) {
            $('#seta2').stop().animate({left: "736px"}, 300, "easeOutQuad" );
        }
        if (top > 2391 && top < 2400) {
            $('#seta2').stop().animate({left: "731px"}, 300, "easeOutQuad" );
        }
    }
    else {
        $('#seta2').stop().animate({left: "830px"}, 300, "easeOutQuad" );
    }
});});
```

But, this code is too long, about 70 lines for a 200px scroll height, is there a better option for doing this?

Again, sorry for the bad english... And thanks a lot for paying attention

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simplify the whole thing with a little math.  Only fire your animations whenever your range changes.  Otherwise you will stop and start your animation on every pixel change.  Also, your current ranges have 1px gaps in them because you are doing `>` instead of `>=`.

```
$(function() {
    var prevRange = -1;
    var range = -1;

    $(document).on('scroll', function() {
        var top = $(document).scrollTop();      
        if (top >= 2200 && top < 2401) {
            range = Math.floor(top/10)-220;
        } else {
            range = -1;
        }

        if(range != prevRange) {
            prevRange = range;
            var leftPx = (826 - range*5) + "px";
            $('#seta2').stop().animate({left: leftPx}, 300, "easeOutQuad" );
        }
    });
});
```

This code finds out which 10px range you are in and then uses that to figure out where to animate to, with the assumption that your ranges are all 10px ranges and the animation ranges are every 5px.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dude! It Worked just how i Wanted to! It is much more flexible and easy to use, and much more acurate! Thanks a lot Again!

Comment: Hey Jeff B, How are you? Thanks it Again, and sorry for pester you again, but, i Want to do it with a reverse to, like, if you scroll more than 2401 it will going to the original position ( in this case: 826 ) as you scroll down, understand? Thanks a lot Again dude!

Comment: Isn't that what it currently does?  Actually, when you are <2200 or >2400 it moves back to 821.  Do you want both of those cases to be 826 instead?

Comment: Sorry for not being so specific, i want both, like, from 2200 to 2400 it goes like it is going in your code, but from 2401 to 2800 it goes back to 826 with scrolling, understand?

Comment: Hey, I think i did it! i'd just copy the original, and changed the values, after trying lot of times it worked! Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 0):

According to the small part of your code, I think you can found a relation between your top and left value :

```
var top = $(document).scrollTop();   
var left = 826 - Math.floor(top - 2200)/2;
$('#seta2').stop().animate({left: left+"px"}, 300, "easeOutQuad" );
```